# Adding text under images (left , center, right)

Tags: html, css

I have a question. I would like to make a few pictures (left, center, right) with text below it...This is what I'm trying to do

```
[image]     [image]     [image]
[text]      [text]      [text]
```

Here's my current code :

```
<img src="">
<p>Some Text</p>
<img src="" style="margin-left:150px;">
<p>Some Text</p>
<img src="" style="margin-left:300px;">
<p>Some text</p>
```

Comment: you miss to upload the css you have tried so far

Comment: @LelioFaieta please, read a bit, he use styles instead of css...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HTML tags `figure` and `figcaption` for this purpose, and then float the figures to the left to get the effect you want to achieve.

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="deadlink.jpg" alt="noimg" />
    <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="deadlink.jpg" alt="noimg" />
    <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="deadlink.jpg" alt="noimg" />
    <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

**Working example:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLGaQp

Answer (score -3):

Do it like this:

```
<img src="" align="bottom"
  height="xxx" width="xxx" />
<img src="" align="bottom"
  height="xxx" width="xxx" />
<img src="" align="bottom"
  height="xxx" width="xxx" />
```

should work...

Or you do it like this:
**html:**

```
<div id="blabla">
 <img src="" style="width:50%;"><br>
 <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#blabla {
width:50%;
height:auto;
min-height:50px;
}
```